# get the highest qulity image/screenshot C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm writing a little program that tranfers a screen shot of a user screen to my wpf image control but when the image is displayed it is not full,not the whole screen is displayed even if the action was done  through my computer and not my leptop and it is blurry

```
Bitmap bmp= 
new Bitmap((int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth(int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
```

the code above is the code to take the screenshot

```
BitmapImage bmI = new BitmapImage();
bmI.BeginInit();
bmI.UriSource = new Uri(FullPath);
bmI.EndInit();
Screen_Shot.Source = bmI;
```

And this code is the code to dislpay the image, `Screen_Shot` is the image name, and the full path is where i put the bitmap image

I tried to use
`Screen_Shot.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;` and `UseLayoutRounding="True"  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"` 
but none of them seems to get the job's done
[this is an exsample of a screenshot i took from my own pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sszpq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `Stretch` property to `Uniform` or else your image will be distorted as it will fill regardless of the `Image` control's size/shape. You also have to remember that the screen size may be different than your programs window size. If you don't uniformly stretch the image it will distort almost always (even if it's just a bit).

Regarding your "blurry" image, you need to specify the rendering option of you `Screen_Shot` image control or it will set the image to a lower quality that it can render more easily. This is honestly better to just set in the xaml. I normally use `Fant`, but look other options [specified here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode?view=netframework-4.8).

```
<Image Name="Screen_Shot" RenderOption.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
```